# How to fetch the records from the database with a custom field using where clause?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I have 20 posts on my page and each post has a custom field called `is_feature_home`. I have to fetch the post where `is_feature_home` checked.

I tried the below code but I am not getting the correct output

```
function getpagecompany(){
  global $post;
   $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'company',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
        'is_feature_home'=>1,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        $tid=$loop->ID;

        print_r(the_title);
        // print_r(post_content);

    endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for sharing the link. This is a great link to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* you must fetch post by meta key so please change your code with below */

function getpagecompany(){
  global $post;
   $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'company',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 8, 
        'meta_key'       => 'is_feature_home',
        'meta_value'     => '1',
        'meta_compare'   => '=' // default operator is (=) equals to 
      );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
        
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        $tid=$loop->ID;

        print_r(the_title);
        // print_r(post_content);

    endwhile;

  wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

Comment: Let me try this answer

Comment: Yes, it's displaying the correct output. If I have to use the more than 1 custom field then I have to repeat the meta_key code.. right?

Comment: like: 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => 'key1',
   'value' => 'value1'
  )
 )

Comment: let me know if you need more clarification for multiple fields

Comment: use get_the_title() function for title and the_post() function for content

Comment: Thanks for the help. i tried get_the_title() and get_the_content() and it's working.